# LINQToSQLDataContext could not be found: Error says I'm missing a directive when it's right there unused for some reason

Tags: c#, linq, directive

Learning how to connect my SQLServere database to my C# code via LINQ. Currently stuck where I'd try to call a LINQToSQLDataContext object, but it claims that I'm missing a directive (Using System.Data.Linq) when it's already referenced and sitting on top of the code:

[Here's the error and the reference to System.Data.Linq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySd58.jpg)
[And here's the "Using.System.Data.Linq" line, grayed out for some reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmGf1.jpg)

I'm not sure why it's grayed out, and the other solution I found only said to make sure to add System.Data.Linq to the project's reference list, which I have done according to the screenshot. Please help.

Comment: You should not be using Linq-to-SQL today (it was released in 2007ish as a basic ORM, it was _effectively_ (but not entirely) obsoleted when Entity Framework was released in 2008 (though L2S had far better T-SQL generation), and then entirely obsoleted when Entity Framework 5 came out (which produced better SQL than L2S), so why are you using it today?

Comment: A `using`-directive is not the same thing as an assembly reference. The error is complaining that you're missing the `using` directive for the namespace that your (_improperly named_) `LINQToSQLDataContext` class is located in. It is _not_ complaining about missing `using` references to `System.Data.Linq` (you will also need to import `System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic` and likely many others).